# How can I create an animation which runs only forward?

Tags: animation

I fail creating a gif-file showing an animation which runs forward and when ready jumps back to start and runs forward again. My files always run forward and backward:

```
Exmp = Export["speed2.GIF", Manipulate[Show[
    Plot[res[x, t], {x, 0, 2000}, ImageSize -> 600, 
    PlotRange -> {0., 600.}, Filling -> Bottom]], {t, 0, tmax, 1}],
    AnimationDirection -> Forward, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

"AnimationDirection -> Forward" is not considered. Why?

Comment: can't run your code as it is missing definitions.  `res` and `tmax`

Answer (score 1):

It is better to make your own table of frames. Like this

[image]

It goes forward only. When it reaches the end, it will restart from the beginning.

code

```
frames = 
  Table[Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, n}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 1}}], {n, 
    0.1, 10, 0.1}];

Export["speed2.gif", frames, AnimationDirection -> Forward, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.3]
```

see this also  [Exporting a Mathematica animation as a GIF and and controlling the animation rate and the direction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256377/exporting-a-mathematica-animation-as-a-gif-and-and-controlling-the-animation-rat)

Comment: Thanksfor your suggestion!